# Randomly generate all functions from R to R

Tags: functions, random

Say I want a random generator of functions like this:

\begin{align}
    f: &\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \\
       &x \mapsto f(x)
\end{align}

It can be usual functions of course, like $\sin(x)$ or $\exp(x)$ for instance. But what about functions that are not defined and can not be defined from usual functions. Where would you start to build such a generator?

Important precision: here I am asking about all functions, but for my application I'm really only interested in continuous strictly monotonic functions. So if you have an answer for that, I'll already be satisfied.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, new to MSE, I came from SO. How do I do that?

Comment: Just click the link!

Comment: I don't think there is any clear meaning to a random choice of such a function.  If you wanted a random family of such functions you could take $\sum a_i\times exp(b_i\, x)$  for random, positive $a_i, b_i$.

Comment: Have you tried reading the tutorial @JoséCarlosSantos linked to?

Comment: @Henrik Leyla Alkan already suggested the correct edit.

Comment: @lulu could you expand a little in a proper answer? I'm not sure I'm following.

Comment: It's not much of an answer.  There is no uniform way to choose a real number, for instance.  Similarly there is no uniform way to do what you are asking.  I suggest you modify the question.

Comment: @lulu I don't really care if it's uniform though. Moreover, this is aimed at computer science, so I can limit real numbers to a segment of $\mathbb R$. I assume I could do the same with functions.

Comment: @Winther I don't understand your comment. Could you expand on what you're saying?

Comment: I'm saying that if you want to do it numerically then you would restrict yourself yourself to some domain $[a,b]$ and define a resolution $\Delta x = (b-a)/n$ (so your points are located at $x_i = a + i\Delta x$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,n$) and restrict yourself to function values in $[-M,M]$. With these restrictions generating a stricktly monotone function is now easy: draw $f(x_0)$ from $[-M,M]$. Once $f(x_i)$ is drawn draw $f(x_{i+1})$ from $[f(x_i),M]$.

Comment: @Winther interesting. But that doesn't match my problem. I need them to be continuous really.

Comment: Add a (for example) linear interpolation between the points and you have a continuous function. My question still remains: is this for a theoretical or for a practical application?

Comment: @Winther, true. But this feels unnatural, and I'm not sure it would solve my problem in the end. Theoretical application (even though it is going to be implemented as a computer program later on).

Comment: You can fit a polynomial passing through all $x_i$, but I cannot see any advantage beyond linear interpolation. Does it feels natural? Polynomials are good representatives of continuous functions.

Comment: @Atbey (and also Winther but I can't notify more than one person): picking some points and linking them does produce continuous functions. However, not all continuous functions can be crafted this way. What I want is far more powerful than this.

Comment: Continuous functions are not that nice. (Eg. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) or another interesting example is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process)) Most of the continuous functions that are interested in practice are much nicer than general class of continuous functions. However, polynomials are dense in continuous functions [[Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)]. Hence for both practical and theoretical purposes there is a great chance for polynomials to be sufficient.

Comment: @Atbey : yup, that's exactly what I want. All those ugly functions. Cantor function looks like it would be a good candidate actually. Thanks for the link.